# how to add a search menu in QT using C++?

Tags: c++, qt

Next to file menu i want to add a search menu that will have a blank space in which we will type ID and after pressing enter it will return the row number or highlight the row in which that entered ID is present.this feature might look similar to what ctrl+f does but the only thing is that i want to add this feature as a menu so that people can enter ID within that.
***the row i am talking about is of a table as i am creating a table with two columns ID and message out of which i want to search only according to column 1 ie ID.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i have created vhboxlayout in which i have added two things.one is menubar and the other is table.
currently my menubar has only one menu ie file in which i have 3 submenu as new,open and quit.now adjacent to file menu i want to add another menu Search in which we'll type the ID and thus after entering that it will highlight or show the corresponding row belonging to that ID in the table present below. @Styne666

Comment: I will expand on my previous comment by quoting the page I linked to: "The problem is that this person’s problem-solving technique is to ask for the solution. Not to seek advice on how to approach the task, or ask for the names of likely classes to look into, or a link to an example - but to just ask for the code, fully formed and ready to go. This is not problem solving, and software engineering is entirely about problem solving."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lazy answer to a lazy question.

You could try adapting the [Text Finder Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/uitools-textfinder.html) to work with your form.